# Do we need to use Fragment Tag for Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I am using a ListFragment and a Detail Fragment. The example from Android Studio uses  tag for the list view.
But i already have a ListView in a LinearLayout. can i use that or should it have a fragment tag. If not, then what is the advantage of using fragment tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `<fragment ..>` tag in xml layout of your `Activity`, your Fragment is automatically committed by `FragmentManager`, but you should either specify a *tag* (which is a `String`) or *id* (which is primitive `int`) when declaring it:

`<fragment android:id="@+id/my_fragment" ...>`

or

`<fragment android:tag="mytag" ..>`

Fragment must have an unique identifier so that it can be re-associated with a previous instance upon `Activity` recreation (on configuration change, resuming after pressing home button, etc).

**For example**, it is useful to have an id or tag when performing calls to:

`FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String tag);`

`FragmentManager.findFragmentById(int id);//fragment id or its container id`